# Rails bundle - bad interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, rvm

I've been working on a rails project in sublime text and switched to rubymine. It said that some gems, which are required in the project, are not installed. Well, I tried to install them, but it fails with an error saying that the used ruby version is another than the version specified in the gem file.

When I enter `ruby -v`, it looked like the same version. I've then tried to reinstall the ruby version (2.0.0) and as that didn't lead to success, I've installed 2.1.0 hoping it would set the correct path and everything.

When I now try to enter `bundle`, I get the following error:

```
bash: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/bundle: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Version 2.1.0 is not even installed anymore.
I've searched for solutions for a long time but nothing really worked in my case. How would you fix this error? As far as I understand I understand the problem and the answers I've read, some kind of link to a path, used by the bundle command, is set wrong?

I'm using rvm for ruby the versions.

`ruby -v` says `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

`rvm list`says

```
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
```

Comment: have you tried `gem install bundler` after reinstalling ruby and point of note, your version of ruby should be same as that in the `Gemfile`

Comment: I can't believe it, this was the solution. Way easier than I thought. If you add your post as an answer I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just added it as an answer, you can accept and upvote

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should run:

`gem install bundler`

after reinstalling ruby and point of note, your version of ruby should be same as that in the Gemfile

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was happening because I had installed **2 versions of Ruby**, and after deleted one of them. The console was trying to get the deleted version of ruby.

The solution was:
**Remove the old version from the environment vars.**

*Observation: I'm using Windows 10.*